# Making a web request with Signed SOAP on C# Visual studio ERCOT

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am facing an issue while making a request to an external web service from a C# code with SSL certificate authentication. Currently I am getting error code 500 Internal Server Error from that web service as response. I had a discussion with the external service team and they suggested me to send the request as a Signed SOAP request. Server is expecting certificate details and so I am trying to send it as a signed SOAP request. I have tried to add it as a Service Reference in Visual studio and I am getting an error there, Reference.cs is not getting generated. So I am planning to create a SOAP request with the details of certificate in it. But I am facing it difficult to generate the contents in "wsse:Security" tag like DigestValue, SignatureValue etc.

SOAP request:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsu="http://www.docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://www.docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mes="http://www.ercot.com/schema/2007-06/nodal/ews/message">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken
      EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"
        ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"
        wsu:Id="CertId-1776694">
        MIIGdDCCBVygAwIBAgIQLReBpu3QZi2DsveIdW4fljANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBm
        MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzE0MDIGA1UEChMrRWxlY3RyaWMgUmVsaWFiaWxpdHkgQ291
        bmNpbCBvZiBUZXhhcywgSW5jLjEhMB8GA1UEAxMYRVJDT1QgRW50ZXJwcmlzZSBU
        RVNUIENBMB4XDTIxMDYxNjAwMDAwMFoXDTIyMDYxNjIzNTk1OVowggE3MTQwMgYD
        BzABhhtodHRwOi8vcGtpLW9jc3Auc3ltYXV0aC5jb20wgccGCCsGAQUFBzAChoG6
        bGRhcDovL2RpcmVjdG9yeS5zeW1hdXRoLmNvbS9DTiUyMCUzRCUyMEVSQ09UJTIw
        RW50ZXJwcmlzZSUyMFRFU1QlMjBDQSUyQyUyME8lMjAlM0QlMjAlMjJFbGVjdHJp
        YyUyMFJlbGlhYmlsaXR5JTIwQ291bmNpbCUyMG9mJTIwVGV4YXMlMkMlMjBJbmMu
        JTIyJTJDJTIwQyUyMCUzRCUyMFVTP2NBQ2VydGlmaWNhdGU7YmluYXJ5MB8GA1Ud
        IwQYMBaAFM9vgLFH3rW5jzTpa58gBemf5RwPMCwGCmCGSAGG+EUBEAMEHjAcBhJg
        hkgBhvhFARABAgMEAZTtjgwWBjQ1MDY3NzA5BgpghkgBhvhFARAFBCswKQIBABYk
        YUhSMGNITTZMeTl3YTJrdGNtRXVjM2x0WVhWMGFDNWpiMjA9MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB
        CwUAA4IBAQB/dbBM3+r8efvt4hGsBhm4gTBqdCG5Gs1zyv4q6tJA2gAokc0QA2f/
        JWBBE1q1iT7f4b9H8yd/dwL2r8LWeCNbKLF7tifYXcC7avgb72FZgiK2bLSYS3Mz
        JtMBcm/hduVHEIhsk+ZFBsQHjIeFnDEANoMOK3A40F3KzsUjg2RG/6G5r9VNcLcv
        rGWATaR6P1s419rdNk1Yr+0mDwchek40s1avn5uMNQAUQDeZgF+L5+OFIzSSjnp6
        p+Ee1dXwmOIASirs3PD43tb/hX5X2Mj4YRuPClnLJXRHGyeVwX3VRaz3YLOXtcsp
        bb7L0aTroePv1U8CXRvQpWbDuApf8jz1
      </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      <ds:Signature>
        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod
            Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
          <ds:SignatureMethod
           Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-1464350">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform
                Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod
        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <ds:DigestValue>
              1JmC1C0FrlPB42xfFKolgaCew5kdedssd=
            </ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
          <ds:Reference URI="#id-13498124">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform
                Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
              <wsse:TransformationParameters>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod
                Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
              </wsse:TransformationParameters>
              </ds:Transform>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod
         Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <ds:DigestValue>
              sEaCJjrObpDVfM8zcvbcbuabwQdBGKbYdssf=
            </ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>
          H1b7jH2bHpbrzJXkFS0msdUYsEaCJjrObycDMH4n6m4oTRtbo4Yk35/JzGcuwUYZ3vfdgvdvc          AwPcnqmcP5ROshjJparaPGuvQhbFR7zCxet2aoawJFWgG8jIeuDZDE8y6n+kbBzxadF2tGN8/nH6IlKg0+onD09i81rPHDAa 2kstCclX2NDet1Rnmfs=
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="id-13498124">
            <wsse:Reference URI="#CertId-1776694" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" />
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body wsu:Id="id-1464350">
    <mes:RequestMessage
 xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
 xmlns="http://www.ercot.com/schema/2007-06/nodal/ews/message">
      <mes:Header>
        <mes:Verb>get</mes:Verb>
        <mes:Noun>Reports</mes:Noun>
        <mes:ReplayDetection>
          <wsu:Created>
            2021-6-16
          </wsu:Created>
          <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">
            75753793-50c2-455b-a9b3-123cb26474cxze7
          </wsse:Nonce>
        </mes:ReplayDetection>
        <mes:Source>Test123</mes:Source>
        <mes:UserID>API_APITEST</mes:UserID>
      </mes:Header>
      <mes:Request>
        <mes:Option>11111</mes:Option>
      </mes:Request>
      <mes:Payload>
        <mes:Reports xmlns:mes="http://www.ercot.com/schema/2007-06/nodal/ews">
          <mes:Report>
              <mes:operatingDate>2021-6-16</mes:operatingDate>
              <mes:reportGroup>60 Day Disclosure</mes:reportGroup>
              <mes:fileName>rpt.00010029.0000000000000000.20091216.093316.dummy_file.zip</mes:fileName>
              <mes:created>2009-12-16T09:33:16</mes:created>
              <mes:size>1412</mes:size>
              <mes:format>zip</mes:format>
              <mes:URL>https://Host:Port/folder/?doclookupId=32423</mes:URL>
            </mes:Report>
        </mes:Reports>
      </mes:Payload>
    </mes:RequestMessage>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

C# code to make request object and call it:

```
public class ERCOTWebRequest
    {
        
        string action = @"https://testmisapi.ercot.com/2007-08/Nodal/eEDS/EWS?MarketInfo";

        public bool GetReports()
        {
            try
            {
                // WebRequestHelper.
                var request = CreateSOAPWebRequest();


                XmlDocument SOAPReqBody = new XmlDocument();
                //SOAP Body Request  
                string nodalXml = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\test\source\repos\WebRequestHelper\ERCOTWebServiceHelper\XMLFile1.xml");

   //             nodalXml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>  
   //         <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:mes=""http://www.ercot.com/schema/2007-06/nodal/ews/message"">
   //<soapenv:Header/>
   // <soapenv:Body>
   // " + nodalXml + @"
   //             </soapenv:Body>  
   //         </soapenv:Envelope>";

                SOAPReqBody.LoadXml(nodalXml);

                using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    SOAPReqBody.Save(stream);
                }
                
                //Geting response from request  
                using (WebResponse Serviceres = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(Serviceres.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        //reading stream  
                        var ServiceResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                        //writting stream result on console  
                        Console.WriteLine(ServiceResult);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }

        public HttpWebRequest CreateSOAPWebRequest()
        {
            string host = @"https://testmisapi.ercot.com/2007-08/Nodal/eEDS/EWS/";
            string certName = @"C:\Users\Test\Downloads\ERCOT_TEST_CA\TestAPI123.pfx";
            string password = @"password";
            
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

            X509Certificate2Collection certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            certificates.Import(certName, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true;
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host);
            req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            req.ClientCertificates = certificates;
            req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            req.Accept = "text/xml";
            req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
            req.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
            //HTTP method    
            req.Method = "POST";
            return req;
        }
    }
```

Currently I am getting an error(Error 500: Internal Server error) while trying to make SOAP request. Someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue while trying to use the ERCOT API, but I noticed that Postman was able to return more information than the HTTP 500 internal server error.  Try adding something like this to your exception handling to grab detailed information from the response stream:

```
        catch (WebException webEx)
        {
            if (webEx.Status.Equals(WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError))
            {
                HttpWebResponse webResp = (HttpWebResponse)webEx.Response;
                string respText = (new StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
                LogError("error in EntryPoint: " + webResp.StatusDescription);
                LogError("output = " + respText);
            }
        }
```